# Finding a ring homomorphism mapping $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ to $\Bbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

Are there any ring homomorphisms which take $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ to $\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: That depends on your definition of a ring homomorphism.

Comment: A map f: $\Bbb{Q}$[x] -> $\Bbb{Z}$ where f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b) and f(ab)=f(a)f(b)

Comment: Does it have to send $1$ to $1$?

Comment: nope that would be a monomorphism I believe

Comment: @user2973447: A monomorphism is one that satisfies $f(x) = f(y) \implies x=y$.

Comment: oh I misread matt's previous comment, I thought he asked if it had to be 1 to 1 rather than send 1 to 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the zero homomorphism. This is because the image of the homomorphism must be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and the only additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is $\{0\}$.